# Is it possible to replace the wire of my Logitech G500 mouse?

Tags: repair, logitech-mouse

There is wear/fatigue on the wire very near the mouse end. I've been slowly patching the wire over time with soldering - each time the closer it gets to being unfixable or reaching towards 'inside' the mouse where fixing it will be hard or impossible.

The wire has to be replaced ideally in whole, from the point it starts inside the mouse (with a white 4-5 piece of wires connection) to the end (of the USB connector to the computer).

So I wonder if there is a way to get a replacement of the whole thing? Or at least the inside-the-mouse connector to a certain length? Are other mice types identical in the connector of the inside?

Answer (score 1):

I am in the process of doing this myself.  I removed the wire entirely by taking apart the mouse and disconnecting the 5-pin plug inside (this was VERY difficult, as I was unable to figure out how to remove the circuit board above the plug, plus it has a post next to the plug, which hampers removal - poor engineering, guys!).

BE CAREFUL when looking for a replacement cord.  Most of the USB/5-wire Logitech cables have plugs which are close to the same size as the USB connector.  The plug inside the G500 is much smaller.  I did not notice this until the replacement cable arrived (was not SPECIFICALLY for a G500), but I only spent about $6-7.  My plan now is to cut off the small plug from the bad cord (leaving a few inches of wire) and do the same to the new cord, solder the old plug to the new cord, reassemble and pray it works.

If I find an actual replacement cord, I'll post again.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I also did the same as the first answer but I had better luck removing the cable. I found that if you take out the whole circuit board you can then access the 5 pin plug with ease because the post is no longer in your way.

I am now in the process of trying to find either a replacement cable or solder on to a new USB cable.

I will also look for a replacement cord and post if I find one.

If I don't post I problem just solder on a new USB cord.